# Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Setting enable_navbar is not accessible from ephemeral package

Tags: java, android, android-instant-apps

From Fabric Crashlytic, I observe this crash happening (on Android 8.0 and Huawei devices)

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Setting enable_navbar is not accessible from ephemeral package mypacakge.com
          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1945)
          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
          at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:651)
          at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:1954)
          at android.provider.Settings$System.getStringForUser(Settings.java:2275)
          at android.provider.Settings$System.getIntForUser(Settings.java:2353)
          at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:2348)
          at android.view.HwViewRootImpl.isNaviEnable(HwViewRootImpl.java:242)
          at android.view.HwViewRootImpl.filterDecorPointerEvent(HwViewRootImpl.java:108)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5201)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5012)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4579)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4545)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4672)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4729)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4579)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4545)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7101)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7075)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7036)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7257)
          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
          at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
          at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

Doesn't seems to be our code. Anyone has any idea what causes this? How could I replicate the issue, workaround or even fix it?

Comment: Known issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72611334

Comment: Should be fixed by the OEM applying https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/577142